# Expo Android Build Doesn't Open

Tags: android, firebase, expo, eas

I'm using EAS to build an apk file to test on an android emulator, however, the build immediately quits upon entering the app. I had similar results when trying to open the app using expo go. For what it's worth, the app functions perfectly on all iOS devices I've tried.

Here are the logs from attempting to run the app in debug mode:

```
I/FA      ( 1867): App measurement initialized, version: 26017

I/FA      ( 1867): To enable debug logging run: adb shell setprop log.tag.FA VERBOSE

I/FA      ( 1867): To enable faster debug mode event logging run:

I/FA      ( 1867):   adb shell setprop debug.firebase.analytics.app com.google.android.youtube

I/FA-SVC  ( 1452): App measurement initialized, version: 201817

I/FA      ( 2578): App measurement initialized, version: 25018

I/FA      ( 2578): To enable debug logging run: adb shell setprop log.tag.FA VERBOSE

I/FA      ( 2578): To enable faster debug mode event logging run:

I/FA      ( 2578):   adb shell setprop debug.firebase.analytics.app com.google.android.apps.messaging

I/FA      ( 2945): App measurement initialized, version: 25018

I/FA      ( 2945): To enable debug logging run: adb shell setprop log.tag.FA VERBOSE

I/FA      ( 2945): To enable faster debug mode event logging run:

I/FA      ( 2945):   adb shell setprop debug.firebase.analytics.app com.google.android.apps.messaging

W/FA      ( 2945): Failed to retrieve Firebase Instance Id

I/FA      ( 1664): App measurement initialized, version: 29009

I/FA      ( 1664): To enable debug logging run: adb shell setprop log.tag.FA VERBOSE

I/FA      ( 1664): To enable faster debug mode event logging run:

I/FA      ( 1664):   adb shell setprop debug.firebase.analytics.app com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox

W/FA      ( 2945): Failed to retrieve Firebase Instance Id

I/FA      ( 1664): Tag Manager is not found and thus will not be used

I/FA-SVC  ( 1452): Install Referrer Reporter is not available

I/FA      ( 2870): App measurement initialized, version: 26016

I/FA      ( 2870): To enable debug logging run: adb shell setprop log.tag.FA VERBOSE

I/FA      ( 2870): To enable faster debug mode event logging run:

I/FA      ( 2870):   adb shell setprop debug.firebase.analytics.app com.google.android.apps.maps

I/FA      ( 3911): App measurement initialized, version: 26017

I/FA      ( 3911): To enable debug logging run: adb shell setprop log.tag.FA VERBOSE

I/FA      ( 3911): To enable faster debug mode event logging run:

I/FA      ( 3911):   adb shell setprop debug.firebase.analytics.app com.google.android.youtube

I/FA      ( 4123): App measurement initialized, version: 26016

I/FA      ( 4123): To enable debug logging run: adb shell setprop log.tag.FA VERBOSE

I/FA      ( 4123): To enable faster debug mode event logging run:

I/FA      ( 4123):   adb shell setprop debug.firebase.analytics.app com.google.android.apps.maps

I/FA-SVC  ( 1188): App measurement initialized, version: 201817

I/FA      ( 4833): App measurement initialized, version: 26017

I/FA      ( 4833): To enable debug logging run: adb shell setprop log.tag.FA VERBOSE

I/FA      ( 4833): To enable faster debug mode event logging run:

I/FA      ( 4833):   adb shell setprop debug.firebase.analytics.app com.google.android.youtube

I/FA      ( 5026): App measurement initialized, version: 25018

I/FA      ( 5026): To enable debug logging run: adb shell setprop log.tag.FA VERBOSE

I/FA      ( 5026): To enable faster debug mode event logging run:

I/FA      ( 5026):   adb shell setprop debug.firebase.analytics.app com.google.android.apps.messaging

I/FA-SVC  ( 4738): App measurement initialized, version: 201817

I/FA-SVC  ( 4738): Install Referrer Reporter is not available

I/FA-SVC  ( 4738): Install Referrer Reporter is not available

I/FA      ( 4692): App measurement initialized, version: 29009

I/FA      ( 4692): To enable debug logging run: adb shell setprop log.tag.FA VERBOSE

I/FA      ( 4692): To enable faster debug mode event logging run:

I/FA      ( 4692):   adb shell setprop debug.firebase.analytics.app com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox

I/FA-SVC  ( 4738): Install Referrer Reporter is not available

W/FA-SVC  ( 4738): Interrupted in onRunTask while uploading

W/FA-SVC  ( 4738): Storing bundle outside of the max uploading time span. appId, now, timestamp: com.google.android.apps.messaging, 1659492068271, 1620436547162

W/FA-SVC  ( 4738): Storing bundle outside of the max uploading time span. appId, now, timestamp: com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox, 1659492068546, 1655839793767

W/FA-SVC  ( 4738): Storing bundle outside of the max uploading time span. appId, now, timestamp: com.google.android.youtube, 1659492068702, 1620436548523

I/FA-SVC  ( 4619): App measurement initialized, version: 201817
```

From glancing at it, it seems like the issue is with Firebase, however, I don't use Firebase at all within my app. Hoping someone can push me in the right direction to fix this and get it functioning on android as well.

Thanks so much!

Edit: After creating a brand new app, looks like it gets the same logs but the app doesn't crash, so I don't think it has anything to do with firebase.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eventually tracked the issue to the favicon and adaptive icon resolutions, works on both android and iOS now (favicon should be 48x48 pixels and adaptive icon should be 1024x1024 pixels).

Comment: Can you reference the link to the issue in your answer, would be helpful for others.

Comment: I don't have a link unfortunately as I tracked down the issue in my commits, however, I added the resolutions I changed them to in order to solve it :)